# Remove all files using its extensions

Tags: php, file

Hi I have created created a method for removing all files using its extensions.

This is the code

```
function RemoveAllFiles($extensions)
{
   foreach($extensions as $extension)
   {
       $files = glob("*.".$extension."");

      foreach($files as $file)
      {
         unlink($file);
      }

    }
 }
```

and I am calling like this

```
$commonObj =  new CommonUtility();
$extesions = array("zip","xlsx");
$commonObj->RemoveAllFiles($extesions);
```

Its working fine if there  is both files are exist else I am getting this error

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in CommonUtilities.class.php on line 356
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use if(is_array($files) && count($files) > 0){ foreach()... }

Comment: Can any one tell why down vote..?

Comment: Additionally, you should either type-hint the argument as `array $extensions` to ensure an array is passed, or type-cast the argument as `foreach ((array) $extensions as $extension)` which will wrap non-array primitive values in an array.

Comment: @Akam The `count($files)` is redundant; if it's an empty array, `foreach` will just jump anyway.

Comment: I am already getting $files is true or false.

Comment: I Don't understand why down vote for this. can somebody explain please.

Comment: @Bracketworks I am always using double checking for being in safe side, mine is guaranteed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) can return `false` on error; this value is not a valid subject for `foreach` and will cause the warning you mention.

Additionally, `glob` may also return `false` even if everything goes fine when it doesn't match any files:

> Note:
>
> On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match
>   and an error.

To protect yourself just protect the `foreach` with a conditional that filters out the `false` value, e.g.:

```
 $files = glob("*.".$extension."");
 if (!$files) {
     continue; // do nothing if error or no files match
 }

 foreach($files as $file)
 {
     unlink($file);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's been answered similarly:

```
function removeAllFiles(array $extensions) {
    foreach(array_filter($extensions) as $extension) {
        $files = glob("*.{$extension}");
        if (is_array($files) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The type-hint of `array` on the argument insulates the first `foreach` against the same issue. Likewise, the `is_array($files)` insulates the second. `count($files)` isn't necessary, as the second `foreach` block will be skipped given an empty array.

`array_filter($extensions)` will remove "falsey" values, including `false`, `null`, and `""`, which may be desired to protect against `"*."` being passed to `glob`. You may want to omit this though, <strike>as I can't recall if `"0"` will get filtered</strike> (*a quick test shows that `"0"` will get filtered, along with `"false"`, etc.*) which would filter out "`*.0`" as a mask - a perfectly valid extension.

```
removeAllFiles(["foo"]);                // no problem

removeAllFiles(["foo", "bar"]);         // also no problem

removeAllFiles("foo");                  // problem! has to be an array

removeAllFiles([false, null, ""]);      // no problem, but no action; filtered

removeAllFiles([false, null, "foo"]);   // no problem, only "foo"
```

Comment: I just tried count only..

Comment: @Vijesh `count(false)` actually yields `1`. That would/could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
function RemoveAllFiles($extensions)
{
    foreach($extensions as $extension)
    {
        $files = glob("*.".$extension."");

        usort($files, function($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); });

        array_pop($files);

        array_map('unlink', $files);

    }
}

$commonObj =  new CommonUtility();

$extesions = array("zip","xlsx");

$commonObj->RemoveAllFiles($extesions);
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($files)){
      foreach($files as $file)
      {
         unlink($file);
      }
}
```

It checks if `$files` is array else don't execute foreach